# Rounding Error in ASP (vbscript)

Tags: asp-classic, rounding-error

I know very little about ASP or Vb Script.  I am trying to troubleshoot an error in which a procedure, written in classic ASP, is unexpectedly rounding to a smaller, ODD number.

As I understand it, Round() should 'round to even'.  Since 720 * 51 / 160 = 229.5,
Round(720 * 51 / 160, 0) should equal 230.  However, the ASP page consistently returns 229.

The actual ASP code is copied below.  The variables in this instance are as follows:

```
FreeElig = 51
RedcElig = 0
PaidElig = 109
TotMlsSrvAms = 720
MlsSrvAmsFr is returning the questionable value.
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you.

```
Sub ClaimCalcs()

Dim tmpTtlEnroll, tmpFreeEnroll, tmpRedcEnroll, tmpPaidEnroll, tmpPct
Dim GreaterValue

tmpFreeEnroll = CLng(SetZero(FreeElig)) 
tmpRedcEnroll = CLng(SetZero(RedcElig)) 
tmpPaidEnroll = CLng(SetZero(PaidElig))

tmpTtlEnroll = tmpFreeEnroll + tmpRedcEnroll + tmpPaidEnroll

If tmpTtlEnroll > 0 Then 
    tmpPct = tmpFreeEnroll / tmpTtlEnroll
Else    
    tmpPct = 0
End If

MlsSrvAmsFr = Round(CLng(SetZero(TotMlsSrvAms)) * tmpPct, 0 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188474%28v=office.10%29.aspx) has this to say about the Round() function in VBA:

> Although the Round function is useful for returning a number with a specified number of decimal places, you cannot always predict how it will round when the rounding digit is a 5. How VBA rounds a number depends on the internal binary representation of that number.

It does not say the same thing about VBScript, but I venture to guess that the same thing is going on.

Bottom line is, if you want a Round() function that will actually behave predictably, you'll have to write your own. :/

(If you want a function that does "normal" rounding, not some fancy-shmancy "round to even" formula, use FormatNumber(). As far as I know, that one actually behaves predictably, i.e. *x.5* will always round up.)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I appreciate your time in finding it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
MlsSrvAmsFr = Round((CLng(SetZero(TotMlsSrvAms)) * tmpPct) + 0.5, 0
```

Adding 0.5 being the addition to your code. I don't think there is a built in Ceil function in VBScript?

Rounding will always go down i believe. So adding 0.5 will result in the output you're looking for.

0.1 + 0.5  = 0.6      Round(0.6) = 0

0.7 + 0.5 = 1.2       Round(1.2) = 1

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't explain the issue well.  I don't want to affect a certain output.  I want to understand the output that is occurring.  Please see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).  As it says, at .5, the round function should 'round to even'.  In this case, it is rounding to odd.  Why?

Comment: If you're explicitly saying (in the second argument) to round to 0 decimal places perhaps that is why it's coming out as 229?

Comment: @Fendorio, please read the question more closely. VBScript Round() is supposed to round to the nearest *even* integer if the decimal is exactly .5. For some reason, it's getting it wrong with 229.5: the nearest even integer is 230, and yet the function is returning 229.

Answer (score 1):

Round is a pain it vbs

here are some functions i found on the internet that have helped me through the years

```
Function Floor(Number)
   Floor = Int(Number)
End Function

Function Ceil(Number)
    Ceil = Int(Number)
    If Ceil <> Number Then Ceil = Ceil + 1
End Function

Function Rounding(Number)
   Rounding = Floor(Number)
   If Number - Rounding >= .5 Then Rounding = Rounding + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Round doesn't work quite like you are expecting. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> The Round function performs round to even, which is different from
>   round to larger. The return value is the number closest to the value
>   of expression, with the appropriate number of decimal places. If
>   expression is exactly halfway between two possible rounded values, the
>   function returns the possible rounded value whose rightmost digit is
>   an even number. (In a round to larger function, a number that is
>   halfway between two possible rounded values is always rounded to the
>   larger number.)

It seems the rounding algorithm isn't quite that clear-cut as even that implies in the examples, and this looks like another example of where the result is slightly different than expected.